# Ubuntu 20.04 will not auto login

Tags: auto-login

I have tried switching it on in Settings/user.
I have tried setting the login keyring to no password.
I have tried changing the "sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf" file as shown in the screen shot.[Terminal screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhhET.png)
I have tried reinstalling 3 times.
Any ideas would surely be appreciated.

Comment: did you encrypt your system?

Comment: I don't believe so. How can I check? Didn't know you could.